# How can I opt-out of 'rtl' by using {flip: false}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to achieve the same behavior as the MUI docs show in this [link](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/#opting-out-of-rtl-transformation). By changing from 'ltr' to 'rtl' the 'Affected' will flip side and the 'Unaffected' won't flip.

I've created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-hw23u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) illustrating the use of `{flip: false}` as described in the [documentation example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/guides/right-to-left/RtlOptOut.js) while following the [steps](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/#steps) to apply RTL.

Expected behavior:

1. The 'Affected' div will flip side
2. The 'Unaffected' div won't flip side as well as the Switch component
3. The 'Unaffected' in nested theme&div will always stay 'ltr

Actual behavior:

1. V - flips side and should
2. X - both flip side and should NOT
3. V - stays 'ltr'

**How can I opt-out of 'rtl' by using `{flip: false}` as I did with nesting theme&div ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, It's necessary to mention you need to use `left`/`right` instead of `start`/`end`! CSS's `start` and `end` are smart enough and you don't need using an extra library to manage ltr/rtl switching. Additionally, AFAIK using [jss-rtl](https://github.com/alitaheri/jss-rtl) doesn't any effect on `start`/`end` values (w/ or w/o `flip`).

[image]

But why do you see both elements on the right side, in the above image? This is because of the use of `direction: "rtl"` and `"start"` and is due to CSS specifications (irrelevant to [jss-rtl](https://github.com/alitaheri/jss-rtl) and [MUI](https://material-ui.com/)). *In RTL directions, **`start`** means **`right`**, NOT `left`!*

---

The second important note is in your case, **both <kbd>Affected</kbd> and <kbd>Unaffected</kbd> elements are UNAFFECTED, actually** (even when you correct above issue)!
[image]
So we can't expect it to has any effect.

---

**Finally, I found out you need to export your bare two elements (<kbd>Affected</kbd> and <kbd>Unaffected</kbd> `div`s) into a react component:**

```js
function ReactComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.affected}>Affected</div>
      <div className={classes.unaffected}>Unaffected</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**And use it  instead of them:**
[image]

The fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-9w61u?file=/demo.js

---

*Thank [@mustafahlvc](https://codesandbox.io/u/mustafahlvc) for [his example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jss-rtl-not-works-when-passing-props-at-css-property-level-material-uistyles-nqfj9?from-embed=&file=/demo.js).*